# Guess these Anime Movies

Tags: visual, movies, anime

Are you fan of ***anime***? If yes this puzzle is for **you**. Let's see how much you know about anime movies. The below image has five pictures. Each picture represents an **anime** movie. Look at of the pictures' components to find the movie name.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1:

> [Weathering with You / *Tenki no Ko*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weathering_with_You)

2:

> [The Last: Naruto the movie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Last:_Naruto_the_Movie)

3:

> [Howl's Moving Castle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Howl%27s_Moving_Castle_(film)) (solved first by @Lae)

4:

> [Violet Evergarden](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Violet_Evergarden)

5:

> [Your Name / *Kimi no Na wa*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Your_Name)

Comment: Thank you for showing interest in this puzzle . Your all 3 answers are right .

Comment: I think 2 might be (rot13) Jbys Puvyqera. Not worth creating a separate answer just for one extra part, might as well add to yours.

Comment: @DenverCoder1 They are still not right . 3rd answer given by Lae is right .

Comment: @Swati New guess for #2. Still not 100% sure about it though.

Comment: hint : rot13( Uvag : Znva punenpgre va guvf zbivr yvxrf gb rng enzra.)

Comment: @Swati Is it rot13( Anehgb )?

Comment: rot13(Lrf zbivr eryngrq gb uvz )

Answer (score 2):

Here are my answers:

> 1. Tenki no Ko
>  2. Inuyasha
>  3. Howl's Moving Castle
>  4. Violet evergarden
>  5. Kimi no na wa.

Comment: Nice try . Your third answer is right :)